# c++ template struct "using type = struct_name"

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <::size_t... Is>
struct int_pack {
  using type = int_pack;
};
```

1. why do we need `using type = int_pack` here ?
2. When we use a pattern like `using type = struct_name`, is there any specific usage ?

Comment: looks like a short cut for your class name, that you can use inside your class.

Comment: The code is taken out of context. There's no way to provide a meaningful explanation without the rest of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `using type = int_pack`, it's just a shorter way to write `int_pack`.

`type` is usually used in `type_traits` for meta programming. For example, [`std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) defines a name `type` if it's template argument is `true`. There are more of these helper functions/structures that define a name `type`. It's just a name that has stuck, like using `i` in a for loop index.